# how to make an image of the newly bought windows system

Tags: images, restore

hi I don't know if my question is asked correctly but what I mean is - I am going to have a new laptop and new system soon, I am not familiar with the technical terms: My situation is:

it often happens to me that my computer gets slow down after weeks or days of using. I 'd like to make a restoration point at the beginning of the new computer so that when I feel the whole thing gets slow down, I don't need to reinstall everything or format or reinstall the windows, but restore to the point like a time-machine.. Is there any such feature already provided by windows 8.1 or do I need a third-party software??

thank you Every body!!!!

Comment: Computers usually slow down when they have too much apps or your hard drive has a lot if files. The best you will be able to do is clear your caches when it gets slow.

Comment: Most computers already come with exactly this built in. If you want to make your own, either use a raw disk imaging system, Windows' built in Backup feature, or something commercial like Ghost or TrueImage

Comment: [How to refresh, reset, or restore your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)

Comment: Windows 8.1 out of the box allows you to Reset or Refresh the system.  If you want something where you backup the entire HDD so that image can be restored use third-party software to accomplish that.

Comment: Reset or Refresh? What's the difference? Do they allocate part of capacity to store everything for future restoration when I enable that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Use system restore if it's a Windows machine, here's more info [click me](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-system-restore)

Comment: This doesn't help him if his system runs into a problem where the restore points cannot be used.  System restore points in other words don't always work.